# config fail2ban on joomla

Tags: regex, centos, fail2ban, vesta

Hello everyone i'm trying to config joomla with fail2ban so i created 
the file `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/joomla-error.conf`

and added the failregex as below:

```
failregex = [[]client &lt;HOST&gt;[]] user .* authentication failure.*
```

After I added this code into the `jail.conf`

```
[joomla-error]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = joomla-error
logpath = /var/log/httpd/domains/jayjezz.com.error.log
maxretry = 5
bantime = 30
```

the logpath is right but every time i try to reload fail2ban service i get

```
ERROR  NOK: ("No 'host' group in '[[]client &lt;HOST&gt;[]] user .* authentication failure.*'",)
```

i think something is wrong with my regex, can someone provide me the right regex for

```
[Thu Sep 28 17:14:23.932811 2017] [:error] [pid 6673] [client 000.000.000.000:56806] user xxxxx authentication failure, referer: http://jayjezz.com/administrator/index.php
```

thank you

Comment: Perhaps you can round out your question with some expected matches and examples of failed text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this by adding a script to change file permissions inside joomla website. now when i cannot login under /administrator without launching the script first